PostgreSQL locking with EF Core 8
I need to apply pessimistic lock on rows while a worker is processing the item, while allowing other workers to process other items in the same table.
My approach is using a query like this in dbContext.dbSet.FromSqlRaw("""select * from schema."table" FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED""").
All other clauses are chained afterward with LinqToEF. As a result, EF will wrap my query with the clauses using it as a subquery in FROM, like this:
select f."C1", f."C2", f."C3" from 
(
    select * from schema."tablename" FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
) as f
where f."C4" = 'whatever' limit 3

I have my concerns, that the whole table will be locked. o1-preview confirmed my suspicions, but my tests using pgAdmin were inconclusive.
I have added a begin transaction; as the first statement in the query tool, but no commit or rollback, keeping the transaction open. And I have started several of these in parallel. The result was groups of 3-3 consecutive rows as I hoped for. Filtering in the outer query seems not to disturb the locking. Even joining with the outer query works.
But ordering looks to break it: once I have added ORDER BY in the outer query, the first one returned 3 rows, but the second one was unable to grab any. Ordering in the inner query is ok.
Is there a conclusive description anywhere about how locking is expected to work under different scenarios?
Better yet, is there any way to add that lock hint from EF directly without rewriting the query in SQL?
[Update 2024.12.12]
I have created a library using the interceptor infrastructure that deals with most cases. At least with mines. It is not bulletproof though because of how limited capabilities these interceptors have. I will play around with it some more and maybe I will release it to the public as well.
